# Accessing text field id of another app

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I am working on an Android project. I am trying to understand if it is possible to access a textfield id of an app which I did not create personally. For example, I want to be apple to modify the search textfield of the amazon.com app by assigning it a value, but all this I want it to be done from another app/activity whcih I will personally make. Is that possible? If i knew the id that amazon uses to identify it, i could maybe send a pending intent to the app with the correct name of the textfield...is any of the practible?

Comment: it is not possible to do that, imagine what a huge security hole it would be for banking apps, etc.

Comment: I see, so lets say i search a video game on the amazon.com app, there is no way i can get this value from the textfield and maybe lets say send it to the search bar of the ebay app?

Comment: if both apps dont provide you with a way to do it, for example a custom intent, no you can't. It's like if I get your account number , login and password and maybe say we send it to.. ebay and I buy a car there

Answer (score 0):

From [Amazon Dev Forums](http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1797) (Oct 2, 2014 )

> Unfortunately, there is no developer facing service available to
>   accomplish this job. It's a great idea and we will share this with the
>   appropriate team.

If you know any app that can do that then it may be possible, but it will be not supported...